# How to change the location where Windows XP caches its RAM or temporary files?

Tags: windows-xp, cache, temporary-files

I'm using SSD as my OS drive, and I can say it's really slow when a painting program uses the undo memory. It stores them somewhere, which I don't know where, but I guess it's using the SSD since I can't hear "scratching" (I had installed the painting program on a different drive).

I want to move all the temporary, or RAM caching (is it called paging?) to another disk, how can I do that?

Comment: A SSD drive has not mechanical parts so its not possible to hear a noise from it.

Comment: @Ramhound, i know, i just concluded that if i dont hear the noise, it doesnt use my HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound: I do hear noise from my SSD, actually! High-frequency noise though.

Comment: @Mehrdad - Thats not possible.  A SSD storage device has no mechanical parts thus cannot make noise.  Are you sure you don't have a hybrid mechanical ssd device?

Comment: @Ramhound: LOL yes I'm 10000% sure. I do hear noise from it, it's just very high-pitched. But it's very very possible.

Comment: @Mehrdad - A non-mechanical drive cannot make noise.  So you must have something else causing the high-pitched noise.

Comment: @Ramhound: Uh, the noise wasn't there when I had an HDD. And it happens precisely on SSD activity (especially bootup). How can you be *so sure* that I'm wrong? Electronic components can make all sorts of high-frequency noise, have you never noticed? Even my *adapter* (adaptor?) can make noise like that too sometimes. And no, I'm not hallucinating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to move the paging file in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307886) Hope this is what you are looking for. Just reread this article, and it doesnt explicitly say how to move location, but you can do it from this menu area.

Comment: this worked! the hardest part was to figure out the english names in my OS language (not english) ! and that route wasnt quite the same either. for me it went: control panel -> system (icon) -> additional settings (tab) -> performance (button) -> additional settings (tab)